# How to use CPACK_RPM_POST_INSTALL_SCRIPT_FILE?

Tags: cmake, rpm

Here is the setup I tried using CMake 2.8.2 to reproduce the problem:

/test.sh:

/CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)

SET(CPACK_PACKAGE_NAME test)
SET(CPACK_PACKAGE_VERSION 1.0)

LIST(APPEND CPACK_GENERATOR RPM)

SET(CPACK_RPM_POST_INSTALL_SCRIPT_FILE "test.sh")

INCLUDE(CPack)
```

then:

```
mkdir build && cd build && cmake .. && make package
```

Results:

CPackRPM:Warning: CPACK_RPM_POST_INSTALL_SCRIPT_FILE  does not exists - ignoring

How to make the build system aware of my file test.sh ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to use absolute path:

```
SET(CPACK_RPM_POST_INSTALL_SCRIPT_FILE "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/test.sh")
```

This is needed because CPackRPM needs the absolute path of the file as CPack does not know that `test.sh` is relative to source tree.